# Evaluate $\int_0^4 h''(\sqrt{y})dy$ if $h(0) = 2, h(2) = 4$ and $h'(2) = 5$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I changed the values so that I could learn from this rather than plagiarize. I already tried to brute force it and get:
$$h'(\sqrt{y})]_0^4,$$
which is:
$$h'(\sqrt{4}) - h(\sqrt{0})$$
but now I'm stuck.

Comment: If $h'(x) = 5$ holds for all $x$ then $h''$ is identically zero. For MathJax it is helpful to put an entire expression within dollar signs. And sqrt uses curly brackets, not parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Community Wiki because I am not sure I have the question exactly right.  But, from first principles:

I am a little worried about the integration there. I don't think it evaluates to $h'(\sqrt{y})|_0^4$.  Consider a different approach: let
$x = \sqrt{y}$ (the positive branch).  Then
$$
dy = d\left(x^2\right) = 2x \: dx,
$$
and
$$
\int_{y = 0}^{y = 4} h''(\sqrt{y}) dy =  
\int_{x = 0}^{x = 2} h''(x) 2x dx, 
$$
and you can attack this by parts.  Furthermore, it is this integration by parts that leads me to suspect you may have been given the values $h'(0), h'(2)$, not $h(0), h(2)$.